# PDI - Kettle, REST API consume error

Tags: rest, api, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to retrieve XML from a Webservice with PDI. I'm using REST Client step and i get the following error

`2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - Can not result from [http://dadosabertos.almg.gov.br/ws/deputados/em_exercicio]
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - Can not result from [http://dadosabertos.almg.gov.br/ws/deputados/em_exercicio]
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - 
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.rest.Rest.callRest(Rest.java:256)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.rest.Rest.processRow(Rest.java:453)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.rest.Rest.callRest(Rest.java:179)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   ... 3 more
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:158)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:271)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:207)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 -   ... 8 more
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - REST Client.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - dep - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Erros detectados!
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - dep - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Erros detectados!
2018/07/18 10:09:49 - dep - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Erros detectados!`

The url is http://dadosabertos.almg.gov.br/ws/deputados/em_exercicio and it works fine on browser either in http or https. Does anyone know what is hapenning?

Comment: Recreated your scenario and got exactly the same the same result, for some reason in the browser network inspector on chrome shows "403 Access Forbidden" for the favicon, but, that maybe it's only a browser aspect.  Just for testing purposes added an slash to the end of the URL and returned the same 403 Access Forbbiden. Can't proof, but I bet it seems like server issue, restricting some kind of petitions.

Comment: Thanks, i think that probably you're right.